# How to convert a MP3 file to octet-stream to send it as POST request

Tags: android, kotlin, type-conversion, http-post, mp3

How can I convert (in Kotlin) a file (mp3) saved on device (Android) to octet-stream file to send it as POST request?

Comment: Just as any other file. Just send the bytes of the file.

Comment: @blackapps Could you take me an example please?

The mp3 file is saved in: `var output: String?`

Answer (score 0):

Edited, after the reply.

You first need to open the file, like so:

```
fun getFileBytes(context: Context, path: String): ByteArray{
    val absolutePath = context.getFilesDir() + "/" + "hello.txt"
    return File(absolutePath).readBytes()
}
```

Comment: The variable output containg the path of the mp3 file